# Create Proxy Service from Template Wso2 ESB

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

**Is there the possibility to create my own template for creating new Proxy services?**

I would like to add an inSequence ("mySequence") for every new proxy created with a custom template let's say "mytemplate". It is the same sequence that has to be in many new Proxies

Where can I find the existing templates? how can I create one?

Please help

**EDIT:** Any example of how to create a template for a Proxy Service? 
[image]